# Nuget saying it can't install octopack created nuget due to .NET Framework incompatibility

Tags: c#, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I am building a simple library with TeamCity and Octopack because we want this library to be shared with multiple other projects.

I am building it successfully and the .nupkg file has the following internal format.

```
   ./{DLLName}.dll
   ./{DLLName}.pdb
```

These libraries are made to compile to .NET Framework 4.0 due to needing to be compatible with legacy applications. The projects definitely are set to compile as .NET Framework 4.0.

I believe the problem is that packages are supposed to be build with a format like below.

```
lib/{DLLName}.dll
lib/{DLLName}.pdb
```

How do i make octopack put the contents in a lib folder like that?

Comment: Indeed. The package must follow a predefined structure. Perhaps this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package

Answer (score 3):

OctoPack is not designed for that purpose (packaging libraries). It is for packaging applications and other distributables for use with automated deployment tools (primarily Octopus Deploy). Octopus [chose the NuGet package format](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/creating-packages/nuget-packages) due to the the ease of distribution through existing NuGet feeds and protocols, a convenience. It does however not follow the official conventions when packing,  to allow a library to be used by a project

From the [documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/creating-packages/nuget-packages/using-octopack#UsingOctoPack-InstallingOctoPack):

> OctoPack should only be installed on projects that you are going to deploy - that means the console application projects, Windows Service projects, and ASP.NET web applications. Unit tests, class libraries, and other supporting projects wouldn't be selected.

I suggest you use another method, such as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio-net-framework)